# How make zigzag line, vertical Not horizontal with css

Tags: css, border, line, zigzag

How make ZigZag line, vertical Not horizontal with css

I try, but I can't

Comment: Please explain what you actually want to achieve!

Comment: And tried code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this you can adjust their size using `background-size` property.

```css
.con{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: 
linear-gradient(45deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%) 0 -50px,
linear-gradient(135deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%) 0  -50px,
linear-gradient(225deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%),
linear-gradient(315deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%); 
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-color: #EC173A;
}
```

```html
<div class="con"></div>
```

Comment: you know click on the right mark on the left of my answer. you can see it in this image surrounded by red boundary  https://imgur.com/gallery/KaHhO

Comment: I try, but https://img2.brain4.photobox.com/228407817c19b7cc68c93f47be7f6fae1172e544533fd5639db732e29cdda96d289886a3.jpg

Comment: you have to click on the right mark not on the upward arrow.